# Can C# "dynamic" type objects always be serialized as a valid JSON?

Tags: c#, json, dynamic

I receive a body in a dotnet core app and one of the fields can be a random JSON. I decided to use the dynamic type for the sake of simplicity (I directly save this in a DB without having to mess with it).

I need to make sure that is that field is present, it represents a valid JSON object.

Since a dynamic object works pretty much like a JSON object, can I assume that any C# dynamic objects are valid JSON?

Comment: Well, technically any data object that can be atomized to JSON primitives (int, string, object, array, boolean) is JSON serializable. As long as the object consists of these primitives and the contents of all arrays/objects on the object can consist of said primitives (and so on) then it should be serializable. ETA: And as Zakk mentioned, there aren't any circular references

Comment: AFAIK yes, unless you have circular references. But that goes with any object structure.

Comment: No, you can place _ANY_ object into a variable declared as dynamic. And as there are many objects you could place in that reference you cannot assume that it is JSON serializeable. If you're only declaring POCO's then you might be able to assume that it could JSON serializable but you have no guarantee. A better check might be to use string instead of dynamic and use a JSON constraint in your DB

Comment: Just because that random field is to be a json assigned to your dynamic object, it cannot be the reason or guarantee for a valid object. Make a json object and remove a bracket from it, you will have an invalid json. The similarity between the dynamic and json that you mentioned above just doesn't guarantee any validness for your data. You can use JToken.Parse to validate your object if you have it as a string instead of dynamic. (From Newtonsoft.Json)

Comment: @JSteward: Fun fact, there are some objects that you cannot put in a `dynamic` variable.  Instances of nullable value type cannot be put into a `dynamic`. If you have `int? x = whatever(); dynamic d = x;` then `d` is either `null` or a boxed `int`. It is never an `int?`.

Comment: @EricLippert Great call out, thanks for details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dynamic` is not a *type*. It just means that the *actual* type will not be known until runtime, and any bindings will be done then (rather than binding members at compile-time).

So no, you can not serialize all dynamic objects as JSON because you cannot serialize all *concrete* objects as JSON. You cannot, say, serialize a stream as JSON because there are too many transient properties that can't be serialized (how do you serialize the actual *data*)?

Comment: It's subtle. `dynamic` is a type from the perspective of the C# compiler's type analyzer, but it is not a type from the perspective of the .NET runtime; there is no `Type` object associated with `dynamic`, for instance. As far as .NET is concerned, `dynamic` is just `object`.

Answer (score 7):

> Since a dynamic object works pretty much like a JSON object, can I assume that any C# dynamic objects are valid JSON?

Short answer: no.

Longer answer: The first part of your question indicates that you have a very, very wrong idea of what `dynamic` means in C#.  `dynamic` simply means "defer the analysis of this program fragment until runtime; analyze it as though the runtime type of the object were its compile-time type".

You don't need anything even vaguely like a JSON object to use `dynamic` in C#:

```
class Foo { public void M() { }}
class Bar { public void M() { }}
...
object o = X() ? (object) new Foo() : (object) new Bar();
o.M(); // Illegal.
dynamic d = o;
d.M(); // Legal; calls either Foo.M or Bar.M
```

There's no JSON involved. Rather, `dynamic` is replaced with `object` by the compiler for the type of `d`, and `d.M()` is not analyzed until runtime to determine if it has a method `M`; the fact that `d.M()` cannot be analyzed at compile time is suppressed.

In short: `dynamic` is just `object` with a funny hat on. You cannot make any assumption about `dynamic` unless you can also make that assumption about `object`.

Comment: "dynamic is just object with a funny hat on" Is it an SO hat?